# transition effect in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, transition

I am currently working in Visual studio 2010 Express Edition For Windows Phone 7.I want to apply transition effects like dissolve,fading,slide at various places in my application.I am a newbie in windows phone 7 so not able to understand how and where to start?
Also I downloaded WPFSLFx library from HLSL Shader Effect Lab..?But no idea how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the wp7 toolkit from here:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034

And use the page transitions.

They are very simple to use, just some xaml added to the page:

`<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>     <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>         <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>             <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>         </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>         <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>             <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>         </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>     </toolkit:NavigationInTransition> </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition> <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>     <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>         <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>             <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>         </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>         <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>             <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>         </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>     </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition> </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>`

Here is a tutorial:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-transitions-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api

Comment: i am already using the same toolkit..but can u give some example code for page transition

Comment: HYG, i added them to the answer

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use Expression Blend for Windows Phone, which is part of the free developer tools: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started

You can have a look at the Expression Blend reference documentation beforehand:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff979338%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx

Specifically, look at the "Animation behaviors" here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff979326%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx

Once Blend has generated this initial XAML, it is a good idea to study it a little further, which will hopefully give you sufficient ground to write some similar behaviors on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```